# OracleSQL get substring of variable as new variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column and I would like to get a new column using only the first two characters. I would have assumed the following should work, but it throws `FROM keyword not found where expected` error

```
SELECT *,
       SUBSTR(PHONE_NUMBER , 1,2) AS MY_PHONE_NUMBER
FROM PHONE_NOS;
```

Try it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/972ce/7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias the table and use it in the statement:

```
SELECT p.*,
       SUBSTR(p.PHONE_NUMBER, 1, 2) AS MY_PHONE_NUMBER
FROM PHONE_NOS p;
```

Comment: rookie mistake... thanks! Leaving the post online, since it does not appear to be a duplicate and possibly others look for the same information